# How can I parse xml content of wsdl using Python suds?

Tags: python, xml, web-services, wsdl, suds

I'm connecting to wsdl using suds library

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://localhost:0000/webservices/WebService?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
```

WSDL contains come xml code:

```
<wsdl:message name="GetRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="types:GetVersion" name="body"></wsdl:part>
    <wsdl:part element="comm:Credentials" name="credentials"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
```

How can I get this xml from wsdl and parse it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to parse the xml in order to get the functions and theirs parameters?
You already got with the object Client.
If you try, `print Client` you should get the information you need.
You can also try something like that:

```
functions = [m for m in client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods]
    print "functions --> ", functions
```

Comment: I want to compare wsdl content from url with wsdl content from local file. This is autotest and I need to verify changes in wsdl.

Comment: With requests so: 
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text.encode('utf8')  
then parse data with xml.tree for example